# WCF Access Denied

Tags: wcf

I have a PC with a WCF service localhosted, I can add a reference to the service in a C# program.  However when I run the program, I get an Access Denied error.  I get no other information apart from Access Denied.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do.  I have another machine which looks the same set up but am able to connect to the localhosted version on the same machine.  I've looked at other questions already posted but nothing seems correct.

Edited....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics> 
       <sources> 
            <source name="System.IdentityModel" switchValue="All"> 
                <listeners> 
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default"> 
                        <filter type="" /> 
                    </add> 
                    <add name="IdentityModelListener"> 
                        <filter type="" /> 
                    </add> 
                </listeners> 
            </source> 
        </sources> 
        <sharedListeners> 
            <add initializeData="C:\Tracing\App_identitymodellog.svclog"                    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
         name="IdentityModelListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp, Callstack">
            <filter type="" /> 
        </add> 
    </sharedListeners> 
    <trace autoflush="true" /> 
</system.diagnostics> 
    <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies></assemblies></compilation>
        <identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="password" />
    <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false"/>
<trust level="Full" /> 
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

and the app.config is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:2745/ActDemo/Service.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
    contract="ActWS.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/ActDemo/Service.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="Act.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>`
```

Code :-

```
using ActDemoApp;    

namespace ActDemoApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string strXML="";
            string strRetXML = "";

            try
            {

                ActWS.IService oService;

                ActWS.Request oRequest = new ActWS.Request();
                ActWS.Response oResponse;

                ActWS.Acceptance oAccept = new ActWS.Acceptance();


                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\Request.dat");
                strXML = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamReader.Close();

                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                oRequest = new ActWS.Request();
                oService = new ActWS.ServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService1");

                // To ignore BindingFailure, turn off Errors -> Managed Debugging Assitant -> BindingFailure


                oResponse = new ActWS.Response();

                strRetXML  = oService.MakeRequest(strXML);

                if (strRetXML == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("XML was invalid");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
```

Comment: You shoud post at least your client and server configuration (from .config file or from code depending on what you use).

Comment: Check code access policy for your code. Seems your code is partially trusted.

Comment: As per request, I've updated the original comment by me to containt the config files.  Do you have any links on what I need to do Shailesh?  User details are correct on the server, just anonymised them here.

Comment: Who says 'Access Denied'? Is it the .NET runtime when you start your app, is it IIS who denies access to the service, at what line of code does it occur?

Comment: The message in the exception, just says 'Access Denied'.  The error occurs when I do MakeRequest call.

Comment: What's the exception (type) and what line does it throw on? Exception messages are largely useless without the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was and quite laughable.  Whilst I thought it was IIS or .NET the cause, I was as close to the problem as a bargepole.  The problem was that the Windows Firewall was set to block everything including network traffic. Question was posted here because I thought it was .NET code.

Thanks Grzegorz, CodeCaster amd Shailesh for spending the time to read and provide suggestions.